# Parent div is not taking height according to its children height. 

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="left">a</div>
    <div id="main">b</div>
    <div id="right">c</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#body {    width: 520px;    border:solid 10px #d2d2d2;}
#left { float:left;width:170px;height:200px}
#main { float:left;width:170px;height:400px}
#right { float:left;width:170px;height:200px}
```

Why doesnt #body surround div#left,#div#main, div#right

If i set display : table it is ok

Comment: You already have a <body> element/tag. Don't use it twice. And if u set body element with overflow:hidden; it will sorround properly.

Answer (score 23):

Add overflow:hidden to #body css.

```
#body {    width: 520px;    border:solid 10px #d2d2d2; overflow:hidden;}
```

**OR**

Use any class (e.g. clearfix) on the parent element.
Refer CSS Trick article for reference:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Using `overflow:hidden` makes my page unscrollabble.

Comment: overflow: hidden (on body) also makes page unscrollable on mobile in my case

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh You can use clearfix the other option suggested in the answer.

Comment: @ffConundrums You can use clearfix the other option suggested in the answer.

Comment: overflow: auto did it for me

Answer (score 12):

The `float` property is designed to allow content to drop through the bottom of the block containing it because it is intended to be used for things such as images which multiple paragraphs should wrap around.

See [containing floats](http://www.complexspiral.com/publications/containing-floats/) for more details and examples.

Set `overflow: hidden` on `#body` to cause the container to expand to contain all the floating elements inside it. Alternatively see [some other techniques](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59).

Another approach, although one that doesn't work in particularly old versions of Internet Explorer is to use `display: inline-block` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 4):

```
 #body { 
    overflow:hidden;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="left">a</div>
    <div id="main">b</div>
    <div id="right">c</div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa: That's one way of doing it. Overflow: hidden; has it's issues too.

Comment: Only when using the new stuff like a drop shadow. @Jawad. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @Jawad 2 articles who say what I am saying?