# Child divs overflow

Tags: css, html

I have a parent div inside which I have multiple divs which are children of parent div, But I don't get that why those child divs are overflowing outside the parent div,

I want parent div to adjust it's height according to the number of child divs inside it.

Heres the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvMNH/)

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879625/parent-div-is-not-taking-height-according-to-its-children-height/10879667#10879667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `overflow:hidden` instead of `overflow:visible`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/CvMNH/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Float #downloads left.

http://jsfiddle.net/CvMNH/1/

Answer (score 1):

Either float #downloads left, or use `overflow:hidden`:

```
#downloads
        {
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
            border: 1px solid #CCCDCF;
            padding: 5px;
            line-height: 25px;
            overflow:hidden;
        }​
```

or:

```
#downloads
        {
            background-color: #EEEEEE;
            border: 1px solid #CCCDCF;
            padding: 5px;
            line-height: 25px;
            float: left;
        }​
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` will make the overflowing child content simply hidden, which, I believe, is not what you are trying to achieve.

To expand the parent div to show all child content, either specify `overflow: auto` on the parent (may have side effects in some browsers), or put

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

as the last child in your parent div.