# DIV container issue

Tags: html, css

So this is probably a very minor adjustment that needs to be made to the HTML/CSS code but here is the issue I've been facing. My code for a general HTML page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<link href="sites/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Services</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 <div class="main_content">


 </div>
 <div class="footer">Copyright &copy; 2012-2013.</div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The CSS for the .wrapper class is as follows:

```
 .wrapper {
     border: 1px solid #ddd;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     width: 980px;
  }
```

I finding that when I put content into any of the other DIVs that go on the page especially when using either float: left; or float: right; the border for the wrapper does not continue on down the page unless I use a class called:

```
  .clearer {
      clear: both;
  }
```

and put a DIV:

```
  <div class="clearer"></div>
```

at the bottom of every DIV that is floated. Is there something I'm not doing correctly here or is this a common issue?

Any help or advice appreciated!

Thanks!

Dave.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parent div is not taking height according to its children height.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879625/parent-div-is-not-taking-height-according-to-its-children-height)

Comment: you could apply padding to the div element in your css.

Comment: Look for [clearfix](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[css]+clearfix+is%3Aq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue, which you can usually fix by adding `overflow: auto` to the `#wrapper`. If that doesn't work, your `clearer` solution is another often-used alternative.